# Converting Date

Tags: java, date

I have thousands of pdf documents. While uploading them to my databases, some of them have converting error which says `[IOException: Error converting date: '£gLùY‹»’î]G…ˇÅìùJÌÜ‡^']`, or `[IOException: Error converting date: 'D:191000724110432']`. The documents that have date error also have the same format as the rest. [image]

Here is my converting function:

```
 public static String getProperDate(Calendar cal) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String properDate = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        return properDate;
    }
```

I also get the same error if I change format as `(dd-MMM-yyyy)`.

Is this error because of pdf or coding? My all pdfs have the same format, but some of them show this error.

I am using PDFBox to get metadatas of pdf.

```
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);
PDDocumentInformation info = document.getDocumentInformation();
indexed.creationDate = getProperDate(info.getCreationDate());
```

Comment: Am inclined to agree with previous comment, a locale problem, that date looks to be czech/slovakian? how are you uploading it? via Web? browser locale, start there and check.

Comment: That code seems unrelated to the stated problem, or at least it's not clear how it is used.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.

Comment: It is Bosnian. I am using Play Framework to upload books in database.  Generally it converts as for example `29-06-2011`. But as I said, some of them do not get converted even they have the regular date time.

Answer (score 2):

Please mention the String decoding format.
Try for 
 String properDate =new String (dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()),"UTF-8");